# Byobu kills windows at will

Tags: ssh, debian, virtual-machine, byobu

I use `byobu` on a virtual server (`uname -a` shows `Linux mezgrman 2.6.32-5-openvz-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 25 01:16:25 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

When I log in to the machine via SSH and `byobu` isn't running, it starts automatically and brings up one window, as expected.
But when I log out and log back in then, `byobu` asks me:

```
Byobu sessions...

  1.  5003.pts-0.mezgrman (05/21/2013 12:37:22 PM) (Detached)
  2.  
  3.  Create a new session

Choose 1-3 [1]:
```

I haven't started a second session though! The most annoying problem here is that after I choose any of the listed sessions, sometimes some of my windows are gone!

I'd be happy if someone could help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in [Byobu](http://byobu.co) itself, in its listing of sessions.  It *should* see that first session, labeled "1" and connect you to that one automatically.  Please file a bug at http://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu with your specific Byobu version number and I would be happy to fix it for you.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: You seem to know more about this, can't you do this yourself? I'd probably not get it right anyway…
And I think I'll use tmux for now.

Comment: At the very least, you have to tell me what version of Byobu you're running...

Comment: I now filed a report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1182776

Comment: Thanks!  And I've committed a fix to trunk.  It'll be in the 5.42 release.  Cheers!